# Can progressive taxation improve competition?

Tags: macroeconomics, taxation, competition

Progressive taxation [arguably](https://vt.tiktok.com/ZS8ncQN99/) supports competition by weakening the profit incentive for large players to dominate markets, while comparatively increasing the profit incentive for small players to enter the market.

However, in practice markets are dominated by corporations not individuals. In most countries, whilst individuals are taxed progressively, companies are ostensibly taxed at a flat rate. (Overall, especially in Australia through the franking credit system, the profit tax rate is supposed to be proportional to the marginal income tax rates averaged over the shareholders, but nonetheless it is unrelated to the size of the corporation.)

Are there any examples where progressive taxation of businesses has been implemented, or theoretically analysed, and did it have any effect on the concentration of the market?

Comment: The flat tax is progressive if there is a positive marginal
tax rate (t > 0) and a positive non-individualized transfer (g > 0) as average tax rates
increase with income (see Musgrave 1979), also many countries which say that have flat tax exempt portion of income making it actually non-flat de facto. You seem to be confused about basic terms which makes it hard to seriously answer the question with reference to literature. Are you interested in actually progressive tax systems, or just subset of systems with nonlinear mtr? Or taxes that politicians do not call flat regardless of econ logic